# Errors with Tesseract in Android

Tags: android, tesseract

I am following this tutorial to include tesseract in my android app. Below is my activity code:

```
package com.MyApp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class OCRExample extends Activity {
    protected Button _button;
    protected ImageView _image;
    protected TextView _field;
    protected String _path;
    protected boolean _taken;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";
    private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 1;
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.datumdroid.android.ocr.simple";
    public static final String DATA_PATH = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SimpleAndroidOCR/";
    public static final String lang = "eng";

    private static final String TAG = "SimpleAndroidOCR.java";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };
        for (String path : paths) {
            File dir = new File(path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                    return;
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
                }
            }

        }       

        if (!(new File(DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
            try {
                AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
                InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
                //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DATA_PATH
                        + "tessdata/eng.traineddata");

                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                //gin.close();
                out.close();

                Log.v(TAG, "Copied " + lang + " traineddata");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang + " traineddata " + e.toString());
            }
        }       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.ocrexample);

        _image = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.image );
        _field = ( TextView ) findViewById( R.id.field );
        _button = ( Button ) findViewById( R.id.button );        
         _path = DATA_PATH + "/ocr.jpg";    
    }

    public void takepic(View v){    
            startCameraActivity();      
    }

    protected void startCameraActivity()
    {
        File file = new File(_path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {   
        Log.i(TAG, "resultCode: " + resultCode);

        if (resultCode == -1) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "User cancelled");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(OCRExample.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState()");
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(OCRExample.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
            onPhotoTaken();
        }
    }

    protected void onPhotoTaken() {
        _taken = true;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_path, options);

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            Log.v(TAG, "Orient: " + exifOrientation);

            int rotate = 0;

            switch (exifOrientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            }

            Log.v(TAG, "Rotation: " + rotate);

            if (rotate != 0) {

                // Getting width & height of the given image.
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();

                // Setting pre rotate
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.preRotate(rotate);

                // Rotating Bitmap
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, false);
            }

            // Convert to ARGB_8888, required by tess
            bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't correct orientation: " + e.toString());
        }

        // _image.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

        Log.v(TAG, "Before baseApi");

        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        baseApi.init(DATA_PATH, lang);
        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);

        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();

        baseApi.end();

        _field.setText(recognizedText);     // Cycle done.
    }   
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at com.MyApp.OCRExample.onPhotoTaken(OCRExample.java:210)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at com.MyApp.OCRExample.onActivityResult(OCRExample.java:134)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4723)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3175)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3222)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:134)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load lept: findLibrary returned null
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
07-17 14:22:49.124: E/AndroidRuntime(15702):    at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:47)
```

What is missing from my project? Line 210 (where the error occurs) in my code is this:

```
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message states all that you need, the leptonica (specifically liblept.so) is not found, make sure that you have that library available at runtime (check library projects imported correctly)